# Travel from North Macedonia to Germany for a week

Tags: germany, macedonia, residence-permits, macedonian-citizens

I booked a one-week flight from North Macedonia to Germany with Wizair. Today I needed to check in and when I provided the North Macedonian passport, it also required me to enter a valid visa or resident permit! Why is that?

I thought we could travel to Germany for 90 days without visa or resident permit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You indeed do not need a visa for short-stays of 90 days in a 180 days period in the Schengen area.

Check if that field is really required and not just a placeholder for if you really hold a visa or Residence Permit. Else, I would suggest you contact them.

Comment: There is checkbox Biometric Passport that I missed. When I toggle it, the visa/resident permit fields are removed. The passports that I have are indeed biometric. Thanks